# pdf viewer for command line only

Tags: command-line, pdf

Is it possible to view pdf documents without having gdm (or similar) running?

Rationale: I'm working on a remote server (assume no X forwarding) processing some data, creating some plots (assume pdf files). And I would like to view them without having to `scp` and open them on my machine. (There may be other use cases, probably.)

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question you asked, but I use sshfs to solve problems like these. I suppose it's like using scp, but requires less hassle.

Comment: @ams, this would indeed solve the copying issue, but right now I'm particularly interested in a command-line only pdf viewer.

Comment: Maybe you could adept [`bcvi`](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/bcvi/) in a way that executing `view-this file.pdf` over SSH runs your local PDF viewer on the `file.pdf` via back-channel magic.

Comment: You can generate ascii graphs with gnuplot, i.e. `echo 'set term dumb; plot sin(x)' | gnuplot`. For improved "graphics" generate tektronix escape sequences, e.g. within `xterm -t` run `echo 'set term tek40xx; plot sin(x)' | gnuplot`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not a real viewer, but as first aid a converter may also help:

```
pdftotext file.pdf - | less

pdftohtml -stdout -i file.pdf | lynx -stdin
```

`pdftotext` and `pdftohtml` are part of the [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) package.

Comment: +1 This works nicely with text-only documents. Obviously displaying graphics without graphical user interface is not realistic? :]

Comment: +1.  Also, `lesspipe` knows how to handle PDF documents.  If `pdftotext` is installed and you have already run `eval $(lesspipe)`, you can just run `less file.pdf`.   It uses `pdftotext -layout` so works reasonably well with multi-column text.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it will work remotely, but locally I used to use `fbgs` ([Info about fbida](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/)). It converts the PDF pages to TIFF files and displays them in a contiguous fashion using the framebuffer. Including images and proper layout. However, it's slower then using a GUI viewer.

Comment: Thanks for this note (it's spelled fbgs)! It looked indeed promising. Unfortunately the restriction is not in the first place locally, but any emulated terminal won't work. Apparantly it requires to be run on any of the virtual terminals ctrl+alt+f1/f2/f3/... :(

Answer (score 2):

If you run `emacs` on your machine (`emacs` comes preinstalled on Ubuntu 18.04), you can virtually open and see a pdf on a remote server by hitting `Ctrl-x Ctrl-f` (to `find-file`) and then type in `/user@hostname:/path/to/my.pdf` and hit Enter (note the very first `/`).  You will then be prompted to enter the server's password and there it is!  You can see the pdf inside emacs.

**Navigate through PDF inside `emacs`**

Use `space` to go one page down and `backspace` to go one page up.  You can also use arrow keys to scroll through a single page if it doesn't fit in the screen.

**Zoom**

Zoom in by hitting `Ctrl-x Ctrl-+`.  Zoom in more by hitting `+` only.  Or zoom out more by hitting `-`.

**Context**

Yes, you can connect to a remote server from within `emacs` using the built-in package `tramp` that works as simple as I explained above.  This method works, not only for pdf, but for any other type of file, such as images.

Comment: Quality is miserable, emacs doesn't seem to re-render with higher resolution when zooming. That said, which PDF rendering engine does it use under the hood?

Comment: @mara004 I think you are right about quality, but other options are rare if not nonexistent.  No clue about the underlying PDF rendering engine in emacs.  Gotta look at the documentation or the source code!

Answer (score 0):

I use ranger, although it doesn't allow me to copy text or highlight.