# View pdf file in terminal

Tags: terminal, pdf

I want to view `pdf` files directly on our cluster rather than copying them to my local machine and then opening them in a viewer.

How can I view a `pdf` file in my terminal?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/pdf-viewer-for-command-line-only

Comment: If you're connectiong to the cluster with ssh, I recommend using SSHFS. It provides a common solution to all “How do I do X with remote files” issues.

Comment: Render PDF to framebuffer

Answer (score 74):

In many systems less uses lesspipe, which can handle pdftotext automatically. Therefore, you can immediately try

```
 less file.pdf
```

which will show the output of `pdftotext` in `less`.

Comment: For people like me who found this and get the error "no pdftottext available" just run `apt-get install pdftohtml` first to get this to work. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570591/cli-pdf-viewer-for-linux#comment40581262_9553096

Answer (score 31):

I guess, it is not possible to see PDF file in terminal but you can check it's content by converting PDF file to text.
You can do this as:

```
pdftotext a.pdf
```

It will produce a.txt file which you can read into VIM.

For ubuntu-variant, this binary is available in following package.

```
poppler-utils
```

Comment: It _is_ possible to see a PDF file in the terminal, like so: `pdftotext -layout file.pdf - | less` (that's how Ubuntu's default `lesspipe` script does it)

Answer (score 11):

I tried the following with good results:

```
pdftotext filname.pdf - | less
```

Comment: This works better for me on RHEL, since the lesspipe.sh script doesn't appear to support *.pdf

Comment: The `-layout` flag can be added to the `pdftotext` command to preserve the formatting.

Comment: @klugerama On Fedora (38) a PDF file opened in less (`less FILE.pdf`) resembled a binary format.

Answer (score 6):

When I want to "view a pdf file in terminal", that for me means that I want to actually see an uncompressed PDF, I do:

```
pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf uncompress
```

I always wondered why both `less in.pdf` and `less out.pdf` give me just text strings in the PDF (and excluding the text-only PDF commands I'd expect in `out.pdf`).

Well, that happens because of the lesspipe assuming I want `pdftotext` being run first - and since here I don't, I have to specifically disable the lesspipe by setting `LESSOPEN` environment variable to nothing; that is:

```
$ LESSOPEN="" less out.pdf
```

And finally, I can view the uncompressed PDF code using `less`

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution...  May I recommend to you the ancient utility `mc`.

```
MC(1)                       GNU Midnight Commander
mc - Visual shell for Unix-like systems.
```

`mc` is designed around text-based file-management, and it has a “view” 
option (<kbd>F3</kbd> key) which will automatically convert .pdfs to text for viewing
without a GUI.  The code which does this conversion is part of `mc` itself, so it does not require conversion by other utilities.  (Also has a native .html viewer for WIW.)

Comment: mc's viewer is very visually attractive compared to the other options here! To view a pdf without opening the file manager, you can use the -v option like this: `mc -v file.pdf`.

Comment: Need to work out how to suppress opening an X application for that extension though on double click. Using bottom menu is well functional.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful, please note that:

- It is for macOS only.
- It won't open the pdf inside the terminal window rather open a Quick look, which I find very powerful to see any file or documents quickly.
  Simply use:

```bsh
qlmanage -p <file_name>
```

Maybe similar command in Linux called (gnome-sushi)
I haven't tested this, but might be helpful as well. I will update this post after testing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
lesspipe file.pdf | less
```

lesspipe is provided by the package less on Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth to consider running `imgcat`<sup>1</sup>. You mentioned that you want to browse remote files. This solution doesn't meet your requirements to view files directly on the cluster but I reckon it may pass as acceptable. Using `wget` you can pass outputs into the `stdout` and then pipe it to `imgcat` as follows:

```bash
wget -O- -q https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf | imgcat
```

This will produce the following results:

[image: Example]

## Remarks

Again, this is not great solution as you will need to download the file (even if you are just piping it) and `imgcat` makes it fiddly to look at specific page in PDF. Nevertheless, I reckon it's worth to post this solution as this little trick comes in handy when dealing with PDFs that contain images, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>Worth adding that there are to packages with identical name, [iTerm's](https://iterm2.com/documentation-images.html) and one that is [maintained](https://github.com/eddieantonio/imgcat).

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is to use command gnome-open

```
gnome-open youfile.pdf
```

Provided that you have login your server with -X option (ssh -X)

Comment: How does this view the PDF file *in the terminal*?

Comment: Not on terminal, but can view a pdf on issuing command from terminal.

Comment: While that is true, the OP did specifically ask for a terminal-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `emacs` on your machine (`emacs` comes preinstalled on Ubuntu 18.04), you can virtually open and see a pdf on a remote server by hitting `Ctrl-x Ctrl-f` (to `find-file`) and then type in `/user@hostname:/path/to/my.pdf` and hit Enter (note the very first `/`).  You will then be prompted to enter the server's password and there it is!  You can see the pdf inside emacs.

**Navigate through PDF inside `emacs`**

Use `space` to go one page down and `backspace` to go one page up.  You can also use arrow keys to scroll through a single page if it doesn't fit in the screen.

**Zoom**

Zoom in by hitting `Ctrl-x Ctrl-+`.  Zoom in more by hitting `+` only.  Or zoom out more by hitting `-`.

**Context**

Yes, you can connect to a remote server from within `emacs` using the build-in package `tramp` that works as simple as I explained above.  This method works, not only for pdf, but for any other type of file, such as images.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
python -m pip install pypdfium2
pypdfium2 extract-text ./path/to/doc.pdf |less
```